# Given a string, how to match all instances of 4 spaces and replace?

Tags: ruby, regex

given a string like so:

```
Normal P start

<pre><code>
        feed &lt;&lt; feed_item.attributes.merge({
          :photo_url = "XXX",
          :full_name ="XXX",
          :meta = "XXX"
        })
</code></pre>

Normal P End
```

I would like to find all instances of 4 spaces, within the `<pre><code>` tags, and then replace those matches with `''`.

Here's what I have so far:

> http://rubular.com/r/Zs6RY3AFXp

Suggestions? On how to do this w ruby?

**UPDATED**

Output before trying to trim the 4 spaces used for tagging as code:

```
<div class="message">Normal P start

<pre><code>        feed &lt;&lt; feed_item.attributes.merge({
          :photo_url =&gt; "XXX",
          :full_name =&gt; "XXX",
          :meta =&gt; "XXX"
        })
</code></pre>
Normal P end</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a way to do this with a single regex, but I'm impatient enough to do it the slightly more expensive way:

```
str.match(/(<pre><code>)(.*)(<\/code><\/pre>)/)
head = $1
sub_str = $2
tail = $3
sub_str.gsub!('    ','')
str = [head, sub_str, tail].join
```

Comment: Thanks but where are you defining $1 $2 $3?

Comment: I'm not. Or rather, I'm doing so by calling `.match`. They're global variables automatically set when you do something involving a regular expression, like match(). $1 is 'the first thing matched in the last regex', $2 is the second, etc.

Comment: ok got this to work by doing x = str.match.... and then x[1] etc... Problem is that is deleting everything outside of the pre/code blocks. which is not desired. The idea is just to clean what's inside?

Answer (score 1):

```
string = <<EOS
<div class="message">Normal P start

<pre><code>        feed &lt;&lt; feed_item.attributes.merge({
          :photo_url =&gt; "XXX",
          :full_name =&gt; "XXX",
          :meta =&gt; "XXX"
        })
</code></pre>
Normal P end</div>
EOS

puts string.gsub(/<pre><code>(.*)<\/code><\/pre>/m) { $&.gsub(/(?<=<pre><code>)\s*/, "\n").gsub(/^\s{4}/, '') }
```

Comment: Thanks problem is that if one line has 6 spaces and another 8 on the 2nd line it is being matched twice, messing up the formatting. How can you tell regex to match at most once per line?

Comment: @Rachela can you please show it in your original question? Just edit your question pls so that I know what you mean

Comment: Updated out in the question, I'm trying to move that all the way to the left, Now that I know it's code I don't need the indents. It would be great to get the indent of the first line and then trim that from all lines?